# Second use of CFileDialog in my program gets the run-time error Debug Assertion failed

Tags: c++, mfc, cfiledialog

I have developed a simple program with MFC. It's responsible for reading and writing geotiff files using GDAL library. For this purpose, I have derived two classes from `CFileDialog` class named `ManageOpenGeoTiffFiles` and `ManageSaveGeoTiffFiles` each have 3 functions to support reading and writing geotiffs.

this is the header of the constructor and destructor for one of them:

```
ManageOpenGeoTiffFiles::ManageOpenGeoTiffFiles(void):CFileDialog(true,0,0,OFN_ENABLESIZING | OFN_HIDEREADONLY,_T("Tiff Files (*.tif)|*.tif|"),0,0,true)  

ManageOpenGeoTiffFiles::~ManageOpenGeoTiffFiles(void)
{
}
```

and this is how I use it in my code:

```
void CInitialJobProject2FinalDlg::OnBnClickedBtnopen()
{
// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
m_oglWindow1.WantToPan = false;
m_oglWindow1.WantToUseZoomTool = false;
CString fullpath;
if ( m_openFiles.DoModal() == IDOK )
{   
    fullpath = m_openFiles.GetPathName();
    try{
        m_openFiles.OpenGeoTiffAsReadonly(fullpath);
    }
    catch(CFileException *e){
        MessageBox(_T("the file could not be opened"),_T("error"),MB_OK);
        this ->ExitMFCApp();
    }
    m_openFiles.ReadRasterData();  
}
else
    MessageBox(_T("you pressed cancel and can not proceed."),_T("error"),MB_ICONERROR);
}
```

everythings ok when I use the `Open` or `Save` button for the first time in my program but when it comes to second use I get the error:

[image]
and if I click ignore:
[image]
this error occurs in the line:

```
if ( m_openFiles.DoModal() == IDOK )
```

of each dialog and even if I click `cancel` the first time,the error occures in the second use of dialog.

**Line 398 of dlgFile.cpp is as follows:**

```
hr = (static_cast<IFileDialog*>(m_pIFileDialog))->SetFileTypes(nFilterCount, pFilter);
            ENSURE(SUCCEEDED(hr));
```

---

**Edited section:**

Answering one of the comments and providing information for others too:

When I set a breakpoint there saw these results when the assertion fails:

```
pFilter 0x00fc3660 {pszName=0x00fc36a8 "Tiff Files (*.tif)" pszSpec=0x00fc3788 "*.tif" }  
hr  E_UNEXPECTED
```

and the results for the first time when the assertion does not fail is as follows:

```
pFilter 0x004cfca0 {pszName=0x004cfce8 "Tiff Files (*.tif)" pszSpec=0x004cfdc8 "*.tif" }  
hr  S_OK
```

Comment: Show us what pFilter points to. What's the value of hr once ASSERT has happended ?

Comment: @Michael Walz I've answered your comment please see the **Edited section**

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a malformed filter string to [`CFileDialog::CFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh5hz49d.aspx). The Remarks sections states the following condition:

> The `lpszFilter` parameter *[...]* ends with two `'|'` characters.